# How to create an admin grid with non auto increment field?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid

I want to create an admin grid which is editable. The problem is that the id column of this grid will be a non auto increment value. Is this possible to implement?

Can any one suggest tutorials or articles related to this?

> UPDATE: I'm using a collection which is gained by joining the magento
>   attribute collection with my custom table. Butin the  provided code below it contains only product attribute collection. `ID` column will contain the `attribute_id`

Grid.php

```
<?php
class BalanceAP21Connector_ProductSync_Block_Adminhtml_Attributemapping_Edit_Tab_Attribute
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    /**
     * Constructor, ensures pagination is hidden
     */
    public function _construct()
    { 
        $this->setId('attribute_edit');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setDefaultSort('attribute_id');
        $this->setPagerVisibility(true);       
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);         
        parent::_construct();
    }

    /**
     * Prepare grid collection object. Collection object populated
     * based on Apparel 21 module settings in admin configuration section.
     */
    public function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('frontend_label', array('notnull' => true));
        //echo $collection->getSelectSql();exit;
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        parent::_prepareCollection();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare columns for the grid
     */
    public function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $helper = Mage::helper('productsync');
        $this->addColumn('attribute_id', array(
                'header' => $helper->__('ID'),
                'index'  => 'attribute_id'
        ));

        $this->addColumn(
            'frontend_label',
            array(
                'header' => $helper->__('Reference Type Name'),
                'index'  => 'frontend_label'
            )
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'attribute_ids',
            array(
                'header'   => $helper->__('Attribute'),
                'width'    => '1',
                'type'     => 'options',
                'index'    => 'attribute_ids',
                'editable' => true,
                'options'  => Mage::getModel('productsync/attributemapping_system_config_source_attributes')
                    ->toOptionArray(),
                'renderer' => 'productsync/adminhtml_attributemapping_widget_grid_column_renderer_options',
            )
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'note_code',
            array(
                'header' => $helper->__('AP21 note code'),
                'index'  => 'note_code',
                'type'   => 'input'
            )
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'note_regexp',
            array(
                'header' => $helper->__('Note regexp'),
                'index'  => 'note_regexp',
                'type'   => 'input'
            )
        );
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        //return $this->getUrl("*/*/edit", array("attribute_id" => $row->getId()));
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }
}
```

My grid is as below.
[image]

Comment: good question. +1 for that. Please add more details to the question ? Are you loading a real collection from database in grid ? If yes provide more details of that. If possible, show us your grid file

Comment: Please any suggestions would be really appreciate

Comment: Thanks a lot. I edited the question. The collection is not from a real physical table.

Comment: if that is the case, please show us the collection that you are using in your grid page

Comment: Updated the question again

Comment: The grid is  loading with the contents. But I have no idea when I edit a row how to pass that row id (in this case attribute_id) to the controller action

Comment: Please make any suggestions. I'm stuck at this problem

Answer (score 1):

To add an edit action and pass some value along with that action, you can use the below code

```
public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array(
        'store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'),
        'id'=>$row->getId())
    );
}
```

This will attach a row url to js event handlers and thus when you click on a grid item, it will trigger `editAction` in your controller file. You can get those parameters like this.

```
<?php
class [Namespace]_[Module]_[Some]Controller extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function editAction()
    {
         $id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, But I'm not using an action column. There's a save button in the grid container, and wanna save all the modifications when the user click that button

Comment: I didnt get you. You said you want to know how should pass attrbute id when a row is edited ? `getRowUrl` is used to do that. you dont want to add any `action` column here. Just add this, then you click on any row, it will trigger `editAction` in your controllers

Comment: Even if this looks like a grid, actually a form container holds it. So There's only one button to submit the form. I'm not going to submit each row

Comment: Im sorry. then what is actaully you are trying to save here.. I mean from the grid page ? and you dont have an edit page here, to edit each of the row ?

Comment: Edit can be done in the grid it self, you don't need to redirect to any edit page. Please check the image I have attached. I think that will give you a clear understanding

Comment: okey got some idea. So when you click save button, what would you want to save ? you want to update every row content ? or those rows which are get edited ?

Comment: only the rows which edited should be updated in the db. So I need to pass all the edited values including id column (which is not edited) to the controller action